# The name of the book/series that had dragons coming back to the world

Tags: story-identification, dragons

I am trying to find the name of this book. The ending went something like this -

The dragons have now come back. One of the dragons comes and lays her head on the fireplace of the main heroine. But somehow she still shows that the dragons are not subservient. And it ends with a saying that the humans will have to be humbler now that dragons are back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is Robin Hobbs' Elderlings series.

There's a lot going on, but the scene you describe takes place at the end of the third book of the third trilogy, [Fool's Fate](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/45108.Fool_s_Fate).

Narcheska Elliania, an outisland princess, has agreed to marry Prince Dutiful in return for the head of a legendary dragon 'Icefyre' being placed on her hearth.

Icefyre is supposed to protect the Out Islands,despite being encased in a glacier and Elliania has decided he failed at this task when he allowed the Farseer dragons to defeat the Red Ship Raiders at the conclusion of the first trilogy.

When Icefyre turns out not to be dead, and the Fitz and the Fool need him to survive to restore Dragons to the world, an 'actual words' solution is devised to achieve both ends.